# Bad gateway with traefik and docker swarm during service update

Tags: docker, deployment, load-balancing, docker-swarm, traefik

I’m trying to use traefik with docker swarm but i’m having troubles during service updates. I run a `stack deploy` or `service update` the service goes down for some seconds

How to reproduce:

1 - Create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM jwilder/whoami
RUN echo $(date) > daniel.txt
```

2 - Build 2 demo images:

```
$ docker build -t whoami:01 .
$ docker build -t whoami:02 .
```

3 - Create a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app:
    image: whoami:01
    ports:
      - 81:8000
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.backend=app
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost
        - traefik.port=8000
        - traefik.docker.network=web
    networks:
      - web

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: 
      - "--api"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.domain=localhost"
      - "--docker.watch"
      - "--docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--docker.network=web"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

4 - Deploy the stack:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

5 - Curl to get the service response:

```
$ while true ; do sleep .1; curl localhost; done
```

You should see something like this:

```
I'm adc1473258e9
I'm bc82ea92b560
I'm adc1473258e9
I'm bc82ea92b560
```

That means the load balance is working

6 - Update the service

```
$ docker service update --image whoami:02 got_app
```

The traefik respond with `Bad Gateway` when should be zero downtime.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Bad gateway means traefik is configured to forward requests, but it's not able to reach the container on the ip and port that it's configured to use. Common issues causing this are:

- traefik and the service on different docker networks
- service exists in multiple networks and traefik picks the wrong one
- wrong port being used to connect to the container (use the container port and make sure it's listening on all interfaces, aka 0.0.0.0)

---

From the comments, this is only happening during the deploy, which means traefik is hitting containers before they are ready to receive requests, or while they are being stopped.

You can configure containers with a healthcheck and send request through swarm mode's VIP using a Dockerfile that looks like:

```
FROM jwilder/whoami
RUN echo $(date) >/build-date.txt
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=30s --retries=1 CMD wget -O - -q http://localhost:8000
```

And then in the docker-compose.yml:

```
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true
    - traefik.backend=app
    - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true
    ...
```

And I would also configure the traefik service with the following options:

```
  - "--retry.attempts=2"
  - "--forwardingTimeouts.dialTimeout=1s"
```

---

However, traefik will keep a connection open and the VIP will continue to send all requests to the same backend container over that same connection. What you can do instead is have traefik itself perform the healthcheck:

```
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true
    - traefik.backend=app
    - traefik.backend.healthcheck.path=/
    ...
```

I would still leave the healthcheck on the container itself so Docker gives the container time to start before stopping the other container. And leave the retry option on the traefik service so any request to a stopping container, or just one that hasn't been detected by the healthcheck, has a chance to try try again.

---

Here's the resulting compose file that I used in my environment:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app:
    image: test-whoami:1
    ports:
      - 6081:8000
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.backend=app
        - traefik.backend.healthcheck.path=/
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/
        - traefik.port=8000
        - traefik.docker.network=test_web
    networks:
      - web

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - "--api"
      - "--retry.attempts=2"
      - "--forwardingTimeouts.dialTimeout=1s"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.domain=localhost"
      - "--docker.watch"
      - "--docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--docker.network=test_web"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - 6080:80
      - 6880:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  web:
```

Dockerfile is as quoted above. Image names, ports, network names, etc were changed to avoid conflicting with other things in my environment.

Comment: `docker network ls` -> bridge, docker_gwbridge, host, ingress, none, web. I do not have `stack_name_web`

Comment: @Daniel woops, just looked again and saw that you defined it external. Is that an overlay network? Can you connect to port 81 on one host and reach your whoami container running on another host?

Comment: Also, do the gateway errors go away by themselves and only appear during a deployment?

Comment: Yes, the `web` is an overlay network. I tested only in one node. The gateway errors appear only during the service update.

Comment: @Daniel an error just during the deploy points to a missing or misconfigured healthcheck. Without a healthcheck, requests get sent to the new container before it's ready.

Comment: I tried with healthcheck and does not worked yet, could you test or provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (jun/2021) Traefik can't drain the connections during update.

To achieve a zero-downtime rolling update you should delegate the load-balancing to docker swarm itself:

```
# trafik v2
# docker-compose.yml

services:
  your_service:
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.docker.lbswarm=true
```

From the docs:

> Enables Swarm's inbuilt load balancer (only relevant in Swarm Mode).
>
> If you enable this option, Traefik will use the virtual IP provided by docker swarm instead of the containers IPs. Which means that Traefik will not perform any kind of load balancing and will delegate this task to swarm.

Further info:

https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/41

https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/1480

Comment: I added this label to my service but it still gives me a bad gateway error after having restarted the whole Swarm stack. I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68054228/958373