# Bad gateway as Traefik fails to point to a new service instance after a failed health check

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a Docker Swarm web application that can deploy fine and can be reached from outside by a browser.

But it was not showing the client IP address to the HTTP service.

So I decided to add a Traefik service to the Docker Compose file to expose the client IP to the HTTP service.

I use a `mode: host` and a `driver: overlay` for this reason.

The complete configuration is described in two Docker Compose files that I run in sequence.

First I run the `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-dev.yml common` command on the file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    networks:
      common:
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
    command:
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=common"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      # Set a debug level custom log file
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--log.filePath=/var/log/traefik.log"
      - "--accessLog.filePath=/var/log/access.log"
      # Enable the Traefik dashboard
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        # Expose the Traefik dashboard
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=888" # A port number required by Docker Swarm but not being used in fact
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.learnintouch.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web"
        # Basic HTTP authentication to secure the dashboard access
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=stephane:$$apr1$$m72sBfSg$$7.NRvy75AZXAMtH3C2YTz/"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs/traefik.service.log:/var/log/traefik.log"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs/traefik.access.log:/var/log/access.log"
networks:
  common:
    name: common
    driver: overlay
```

Then I run the `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml www_learnintouch` command on the file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  www:
    image: localhost:5000/www.learnintouch
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/data:/usr/local/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/backup:/usr/local/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/backup"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/local/learnintouch/engine"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/conf/live/thalasoft.com:/usr/local/learnintouch/letsencrypt"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/apache/logs"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/learnintouch/logs"
    user: "${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_GID}"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.www.rule=Host(`dev.learnintouch.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.www.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.www.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:80/engine/ping.php || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
networks:
  common:
    external: true
    name: common
```

Here are the networks:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                      DRIVER    SCOPE
6beaf0c3a518   bridge                    bridge    local
ouffqdmdesuy   common                    overlay   swarm
17et43c5tuf0   docker-registry_default   overlay   swarm
1ae825c8c821   docker_gwbridge           bridge    local
7e6b4b7733ca   host                      host      local
2ui8s1yomngt   ingress                   overlay   swarm
460aad21ada9   none                      null      local
tc846a14ftz5   verdaccio                 overlay   swarm
```

The `docker ps` command shows that all containers are healthy.

But a request to `http://dev.learnintouch.com/` responds with a `Bad Gateway` error MOST of the times except when rarely it does not and the web application displays fine.

As a side note, I would like any unhealthy service to be restarted and seen by Traefik. Just like Docker Swarm restarts unhealthy services I would like Traefik to restart unhealthy services too.

The service log:

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"dashboard\":{\"service\":\"api@internal\",\"rule\":\"Host(`traefik.learnintouch.com`)\"},\"nodejs\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"service\":\"nodejs\",\"rule\":\"Host(`dev.learnintouch.com`)\"},\"traefik\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"middlewares\":[\"traefik-auth\"],\"service\":\"traefik\",\"rule\":\"Host(`common-reverse-proxy`)\"},\"www\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"service\":\"www\",\"rule\":\"Host(`dev.learnintouch.com`)\"}},\"services\":{\"nodejs\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://10.0.14.17:9001\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"traefik\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://10.0.14.8:888\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"www\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://10.0.14.18:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}},\"middlewares\":{\"traefik-auth\":{\"basicAuth\":{\"users\":[\"stephane:$apr1$m72sBfSg$7.NRvy75AZXAMtH3C2YTz/\"]}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}","providerName":"docker","time":"2021-07-04T10:25:01Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Skipping same configuration","providerName":"docker","time":"2021-07-04T10:25:01Z"}
```

I also tried to have Docker Swarm doing the load balancing with adding the `- "traefik.docker.lbswarm=true"` property to my service but the `Bad Gateway` error remained.

I also restarted the Swarm manager:

```
docker swarm leave --force
docker swarm init
```

but the `Bad Gateway` error remained.

I also added the two labels:

```
- "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky=true"
- "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
```

but the `Bad Gateway` error remained.

It feels like Traefik hits the web service before that one has a chance to be ready. Would there be any way to tell Traefik to wait a given amount of seconds before hitting the web service ?

UPDATE: I could find, not a solution, but a workaround the issue, by splitting the first above `common` stack file into two files, with one dedicated to the `traefik` stack. I could then start the 3 stacks in the following order: `common`, `www_learnintouch` and `traefik`
The important thing was to start the `traefik` stack after the others. If I then had to remove and start again the `www_learnintouch` stack for example, then I had to follow this by removing and starting again the `traefik` stack.
Also, if I removed the container of `www_learnintouch` with a `docker rm -f CONTAINER_ID` command then I also needed to remove and start again the `traefik` stack.